# Paraview 3.98.1 settings

Tags: settings, paraview

I am using Paraview 3.98.1 for picture generation.
I have a python script which calls paraview to generate pictures.

The problem is that whenever the python script calls paraview, paraview opens only in a small screen and not in a full screen mode. This creates bad pictures.

I tried to change the settings in Edit-settings by disabling the splash screen so that i can get paraview in full screen mode. But everytime i close and open paraview the settings are reset.

I am also attaching a screen shot for better understanding.[This is what i get when i open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcnYt.png).

[This is what i need when i open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v87U7.png)

anyone knows a solution for this?

Comment: Hello. There are commands in paraview python scripts to set the size of the render windows. How do you generate the pictures ?

Comment: Sry @BertrandGazanion i didnt get your question on how do you generate pictures.
The script works fine and it generates pictures. The problem is that paraview is opening in a minimized window and not in a maximized window.

Answer (score 0):

To increase the size of the pictures one can modify the size of the render window, or export the pictures with a magnification factor > 1.

Here is the python commands to modify the size of the render window :

```
GetActiveView().ViewSize = [2000, 1500]
```

If you export the picture with `SaveScreenshot`, you can set a magnification factor > 1 by adding the `magnification` parameter (integer value). The picture size will then be the `ViewSize` multiplied by this factor.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Actually this solved another problem of mine. but the actual problem still exist. For a better understanding i have attached the link of the screenshots in my original post. Please have a look at it

Comment: OK, my bad. I understand now that you need a command line way to launch any program fullscreen on Linux (gnome 2 ?). And from python ? I don't know how to do this. If that is really your question, you should maybe ask this question with a general linux and/or python tag.